# jQuery - Given a table of rows how to disable a Submit button based on the row

Tags: jquery

I have a table with several rows of data. Each row is it's own entity. It's not all associated to one form. Essentially each row is a form:

http://jsfiddle.net/NmpaM/

How can I use jQuery to say: for that row, if fName, lName and email are not blank, and email is valid. Enable the submit button. If not, disable the submit button?

Goal is to make sure each row is valid before allowing the user to submit. And then after submit, having control to remove the row?

Thoughts Thanks

Comment: Can you add a row number to each field?  (e.g. first_name_1, last_name_1 )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it (see [jsfiddle.net/marke/mvBNS](http://jsfiddle.net/marke/mvBNS/)):

```
jQuery(function() {
    // You may want to use a different regular expression;
    // this is just the first one I found on the 'net   
    var email_regex = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;

    function validateRow(tr) {
        var valid = true;
        tr.find('input[type="text"]').each(function(i, el) {
            if (!el.value.replace(' ', '')) return valid = false;
            if (el.name == 'email' && !email_regex.test(el.value)) return valid = false;
        });
        tr.find('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', valid? null : 'disabled');
    }

    jQuery('tr').each(function(i, el) {
        validateRow(jQuery(this));
    }).find('input[type="text"]').change(function() {
        validateRow(jQuery(this).closest('tr'));
    });
});
```

Comment: That's very nice but it only enables the submit button onblur. So that would require the user to know to move out of the input box which isn't likely. Any way to get it to update on keyup vs blur?

Comment: Just find and replace ".change(" to ".keyup(".

Comment: @AnApprentice `.bind('change keyup', fn)` instead of `.change(fn)` near the bottom....

Answer (score 1):

What you're basically looking for is form validation, correct?  There are a variety of jQuery form validation plugins out there that will implement the behavior you're looking for.  You can define validation rules for each field and if those rules don't pass, the user won't be able to submit the form.  This type of behavior should be common in pretty much any jQuery plugin you go with.

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ should get you started.  There are others too.

Answer (score 1):

Copy and paste this into a javascript console on that frame and you'll be good to go.
http://fiddle.jshell.net/NmpaM/show/

```
valid_email_regx = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;

// add change event to each text box
$("table :text").change( function(){

    // Select every field in row
    $(this).parents("tr").find(":text").each(function(index){

        // If field fails validation, disable field and exit loop
        if($(this).val() == '' || ($(this).attr("id") == "email" && !valid_email_regx.test( $(this).val() ) ) ){
            $(this).parents("tr").find(":submit").attr("disabled", true);
            return false;
        }else
            $(this).parents("tr").find(":submit").attr("disabled", false);  
    })

});

// Add this to $(document).ready() to initally run function
$("table :text").change()
```

(You'll want to change "table" to a specific id.)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.I have given a id to table to identify it

```
 var tbody = $('#tableId');
    var trs = tbody.children();
    var row = 0;
    for (row = 0; row < trs.length; row++) {
        var txts = trs[row].getElementsByTagName('input');
        var isFilled=false;
        for (i = 0; i < txts.length; i++) {
            if(txts[i].type=='text'){
            isFilled=checkRequired(txts[i])   && isFilled
                }
        }

        if(isFilled){
        trs[row].getElementsByTagName('input');
             for (i = 0; i < txts.length; i++) {
            if(txts[i].type=='submit'){
                   txts[i].enabled=true;//set your css values here
                }
        }


        }

    }


 function checkRequired(o) {
     if (o.value== null || o.value =='') {

         return false;
     } else {

         return true;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You should only really bother reading this post if you are avoiding implementing some of the already powerful form validation plugins available to you as mentioned by other answers.

You could do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/gnarf/NmpaM/3/

```
function checkForms() {
    var rempty = /^\s*$/,
        remail = /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/,
        // narrow the scope of the check when called as an event handler
        check = (this.nodeType) ? $(this).closest('tr') : $('tr');

    check.each(function() {
        var $row = $(this),
            $inputs = $row.find("input.text_field"),
            $btn = $row.find('input.button[name="commit"]'),
            $email = $row.find('input[name="email"]'),
            numempty = $inputs.filter(function() {
                return rempty.test(this.value);
            }).length;

        if (numempty > 0 || !remail.test($email.val())) $btn.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        else $btn.removeAttr('disabled');
    });
}
checkForms();
// just so it updates everytime the input changes:
$("input").bind('change keyup', checkForms);
```

Answer (score -2):

Why do not you use php to verification?

for example:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
  <? if ($row['email'] != "") { echo "<form method='post' action='pageAct.php'> <input type='submit' name='x' value='y'> </form>"; } ?>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and do that inside a loop while for instance.

Comment: You should be using server side validation ALSO, but stopping the user from being able to submit a form you know the server will complain about is what this question is about...

Comment: was just a try! It is only client side, okay. disregard about the answer.!